# Sendinblue SMTP not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendinblue

I am using CodeIgniter and I have set up a bunch of emails for my customers and sending them through SMTP ... Now the requirement of the job is to use Sendinblue for sending emails... So I simply replaced my SMTP credentials with ones provided by Sendinblue... and mails are not being sent.. please help

Older Code (When mails were sending)

```
$config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp', // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
                'smtp_host' => smtp.example.com,
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => MY_USER,
                'smtp_pass' => '',

                'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl', //can be 'ssl' or 'tls' for example
                'mailtype' => 'html', //plaintext 'text' mails or 'html'
                'smtp_timeout' => '4000', //in seconds
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );
```

SendinBlue SMTP details (mails are not working now)

```
$config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp', // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
                'smtp_host' => smtp-relay.sendinblue.com,
                'smtp_port' => 587,
                'smtp_user' => MY_USER,
                'smtp_pass' => MY_PASS,

                'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl', //can be 'ssl' or 'tls' for example
                'mailtype' => 'html', //plaintext 'text' mails or 'html'
                'smtp_timeout' => '4000', //in seconds
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging, or checked any error logs or anything? You haven't given us any info which we could use to help you. We have no idea if the connection details or credentials are correct (and nor should we, it's your account!), or whether some other issue (e.g. firewall perhaps) is blocking you. You need to provide debug info.

Comment: @ADyson, Strange thing is I am not receiving any erros.. if there's any special way to debug mailing stuff, please do let me know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative simple solution.. pasting my answer if anyone needs in future...
I have used this CURL request, Mailin Provided by SendinBlue

https://github.com/mailin-api/mailin-api-php/tree/master/src/Sendinblue